# Connection timed out on specific ports

Tags: networking, firewall

We have an apache server running couchdb on port 5985 (not 5984).
On my computer, I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14 LTS. From Ubuntu, I can connect to the host via http://example.server.domain, but I can't connect to http://example.server.domain:5985.
I tryed both from Chrome and from Firefox. This is working on Windows on the same computer.

I also can't connect to our sftp server with filezilla (I get "Connection timed out"), but I can connect to this sever with WinSCP from Windows.

Everything else is working great. All the other websites are working, I can install packages using apt-get, I can pull and push docs with git...

I tried shutting down firewall with ufw disable (and rebooted after that), but it didn't work.

Oh... and I think I should mention ping isn't working right:

```
root@ThinkCentre-M92p:/home/gxgung# ping google.ro
PING google.ro (81.12.207.80) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.ro ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7054ms

root@ThinkCentre-M92p:/home/gxgung# ping google.com
PING google.com (81.12.207.85) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8063ms

root@ThinkCentre-M92p:/home/gxgung# ping kappa.ro
PING kappa.ro (78.96.79.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- kappa.ro ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7056ms

root@ThinkCentre-M92p:/home/gxgung#
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by switching from DHCP to Static. It seems there was a problem in the network and the default DHCP settings allowed me to access the internet but hindered other functions.